# MySQL Query help on a use case

Tags: mysql

My apologies, I am really new to SQL and hence such silly questions.

I have a database schema like below :

[image: table-structure]

I want to get the minimum cost of a certain dish in the table `dishes`. for example - Berry Bread requires 2 fruits i.e. Cranberry and Blackberry of which the prices are available in the vendor_fruit_prices.

The output should be the summation of minimum prices of both the fruits along the vendor.

I tried

```
select dish, vendor_fruit_prices.fruit_id, min(price) from dishes,dishes_fruits,vendor_fruit_prices
where dishes.id=dishes_fruits.dish_id and 
dishes_fruits.fruit_id=vendor_fruit_prices.fruit_id
group by dish,vendor_fruit_prices.fruit_id;
```

But the output is coming out to be -

[image]

I have the minimum price of fruit required by the vendor in the result.Can anyone help me to understand how can I get the sum of the rows having same dish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to sum the prices and include a subquery to get the minimum price of the fruit item. I've also included a list of fruit_id values used per dish using the Group_Concat (Group Concatenate) command which returns all values in a single cell:

```
Select
    dish
    ,Group_Concat(Distinct f.id SEPARATOR ', ') fruitIds
    ,Sum(price) minPrice
From
    dishes d
    join dishes_fruits df on d.id = df.dish_id
    join fruits f on df.fruit_id = f.id
    join vendor_fruit_prices vfp on f.id = vfp.fruit_id and price = (Select Min(price) From vendor_fruit_prices where fruit_id = f.id)
    join vendors v on vfp.vendor_id = v.id
Group By
    dish;
```